# Explain why $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{x+1}= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{x+1}$ and what does the Mean Value Theorem have to do with it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My Calculus 1 professor gave us this problem to help us prepare for the final exam. I can show $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{x+1}= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{x+1}$ and explain why $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{x+1}= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{x+1}$ is the case, but I have no idea what it has to do with the Mean Value Theorem.

Could someone please help me understand what the Mean Value Theorem has to do with this?

> **Mean Value Theorem:**
>
> If $f(x)$ is defined and continuous on the interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there is at least one number $c$ such that
>
> $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
>
> **Problem Text:**
>
> Show that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{x+1}= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{-1}{x+1}$ even though $\frac{x}{x+1} \neq \frac{-1}{x+1}$. Why is this true and what does the Mean Value Theorem have to do with it?

Comment: Easiest way to show this is that $$\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{(x+1)-1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$ so for $x\neq -1$ these functions differ by a constant and thus the derivatives are the same.

Comment: @Dave What does that have to do with the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Don't know if this is the argument that they want, but one way it could be related is to note that the mean value theorem relates differences between function values $f(b) - f(a)$ to the derivative $f'(x)$. If you have two functions that only differs by a constant then this difference is the same for these two functions so it must have the same derivative. In other words, the mean value theorem is often used to prove the fact you know very well that $f'(x) = 0 \implies f(x) = C$ which is what you use when you show that $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1+x} = -\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say what your professor is getting at with "what does the mean value theorem have to do with it?"—maybe they want you to let $f(x) = x$ and apply the mean value theorem with $b=x$ and $a=-1$. Then you get
$$f'(c) = \dfrac{x-(-1)}{x-(-1)} = \dfrac{x}{x+1} - \dfrac{-1}{x+1}$$
for some $c$ between $1$ and $x$. But $f'(c)=1$ for all $c$, so you see that $\dfrac{x}{x+1}$ and $\dfrac{-1}{x+1}$ differ by a constant, so their derivatives are equal.

...but you certainly don't need the mean value theorem to see that they differ by a constant! Indeed:
$$\dfrac{x}{x+1} = \dfrac{(x+1) - 1}{x+1} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{x+1}$$

Comment: I would bet this is the "intended" solution.